# Security Packages for all Platforms

Tags: c#, iphone, android, wcf, encryption

I'm looking for a framework or a package that provides me to encrypt decrypt via services. I'm generally using WCF as a web-service and most of the mobile platforms such as should send to web-service encrypted messages that is suitable between each other. It doesn't matter whether it is free or not. Please note that, it is better to be that the framework supports AES256 encryption as well.

Regards , 
Kemal

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use HTTPS and you don't have to bother with message security at all. I haven't seen yet any API supporting WS-Security and related standards (= message security) on Android or iPhone.

Comment: However, I need to make some kind of encryption in order to make an authentication. I got a request and response objects that are transmitted between mobile devices and wcf. However, end user will know what they send and what they get. In order to prevent end user to create request and consume my WCF service, I need to send an encrypted data that needs to be decrypted correctly on my wcf service. So that, wcf service can determine whether it should return response or not. That's why I'm looking for an encryption framework for both sides.

Comment: HTTPS performs encryption on transport level.

Comment: How could this be accepted as an answer? The meaning of SOAP WebServices is, that a provider provides some remote procedures to the outside world described by WSDL an following the WS standards. If he says YOU HAVE USE WS-SECURITY TO CONSUME MY SERVICES than you can do whatever you want, but unless you send a WS-Security conform request you won't be able to consume the service. I cannot write for example to Google and say heeey guuys could you please turn of your message security for me and use just HTTPs??? The message security has its meaning against the channel security.

Comment: @FilipMajernik: Yes you are right but this question was about server side when you develop a service which should be consumed by mobile platforms and in such case HTTPS is way to go to avoid problems with developing clients.